# Error in switch(class(arraydata), matrix = { : EXPR must be a vector of length 1

Tags: r, function, class, switch-statement, ord

I would like to know if someone got a similar error using the `ord` `function`?
My code hasn't worked since using the new version of `R (4.0.2)` and I wonder if it's associated with `made4` updates?

I would really appreciate it if someone would give some hint

This is the problematic piece of code

```
res_coa <- ord(tdata, classvec=Species, type="coa")
```

where `tdata` is a `matrix` and `Species` a `factor`

Comment: Since R 4.0 `class(matrix(1))` returns a length 2 vector. I'd say this is a bug in the package.

Comment: Try turning your matrix into one of the other supported input classes. (And report the bug to the package maintainer. They should fix this and add a unit test.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Roland. I tried before I posted a problem with other classes, and it didn't work. So, I will go for another suggestion.
Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it just converting my data into a data.frame. You can try something like:

```
res_coa <- ord(data.frame(tdata), classvec=Species, type="coa")
```